# python plotly find Cross between two lines with two distinct dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

[image]

Hello,

I'm using plotly to plot this figure and use two distinct lists.
I want to create an annotation on the graph when the lines intersect each other, can anyone help me with this intersection.
The x axis is the same for both lists.

Answer (score 1):

If the X-axis is identical, this can be easily done by checking where the lists are equal without having to worry about crossing-algorithms.
Using numpy you can apply boolean masks to lists. This code creates a boolean mask for equality, then extracts the timestamp and value at the TRUE (equal) indeces. These you can then use to add a Scatter trace with for example red marks and text annotation.

```
import numpy as np

t = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])  # fake time series

a = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])  # list A
b = np.array([10,9,8,7,6])    # list B

mask = np.array([a[ix]==b[ix] for ix, _ in enumerate(a)])  # get the indeces of equal items

new_t = t[mask]  # get the timestamps
marks = a[mask]  # get the values

print(new_t, marks)
```

If it needs a true crossing check, having the same X-axis is still useful. You can then add a check for a change of sign in the difference between the lists around the equality.

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for your answer.
If you see, on the image, the values on both arrays are completly differents. On the left side i have a range between 100k and 120k and on the right side i have between 0 and 3. 
I need to check if the cross like on image, after plot the graph.

Comment: In that case: you know the scaling between the two lists. So create a copy of one list, scale it with the conversion factor to the other range and then do the check.

Comment: can you please send me a example pls, to understand your idea

Comment: Please add the code you used to create the graph, then I can modify it.

Comment: oiDataFrame["oi"] = oiDataFrame["oi"].astype(float)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=oiDataFrame["date"],y=oiDataFrame["oi"],mode="lines"),row=3, col=1)
                
lsrDataFrame["lsr"] = lsrDataFrame["lsr"].astype(float) fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=lsrDataFrame["date"],y=lsrDataFrame["lsr"],mode="lines",yaxis='y2'),row=3, col=1,secondary_y=True)

Comment: Where do you define the y_axis range for both y1 and y2? Without that definition, the visual crossing of the graphs is mathematically meaningless.